# Flash P2P or FMS?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I am trying to connect 2 flash clients to a flash game, each client will control a object in the flash game.

I am unsure of how I can connect those two clients to the central flash game, or what the best way would be to achieve the desired result.

So basically I am just trying to send commands from the flash clients to the flash game, but I am unsure of how to go about it.

Would P2P or a FMS solution work best?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use FMS or P2P. Check out [Getting started with Flash Platform game development](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-flash-games.html). It starts with game market information and goes into design, but then has links to learning ActionScript and learning how to develop games specifically.